# Bigquery crashlytics dataset schedule interval

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics, bq

We're currently looking into Firebase<>BigQuery (not sandboxed) for monitoring purposes. We've hooked up one of our projects using the Firebase integration and have gathered a few days worth of data.

Only the data is always a day off, which makes sense since the transfer only runs every 24 hours. But trying to change it through the bq cli:

```sh
bq update --transfer_config \
  --target_dataset='crashlytics' \
  --schedule='every 2 hours' \
  projects/p/locations/l/transferConfigs/c
```

results into a 400 error:

```
Bigquery service returned an invalid reply in update operation: Error reported by server with missing error fields. Server returned: {u'error': {u'status': u'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
u'message': u'Request contains an invalid argument.', u'code': 400}}.

Please make sure you are using the latest version of the bq tool and try again. If this problem persists, you may have encountered a bug in the bigquery client. Please file a bug
report in our public issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0
Please include a brief description of the steps that led to this issue, as well as any rows that can be made public from the following information:

========================================
== Platform ==
  CPython:2.7.16:Darwin-19.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
== bq version ==
  2.0.53

== Command line ==
  ['/path/bq/bq.py', '--application_default_credential_file', '/path/e@mail.com/adc.json', '--credential_file', '/path/e@email.com/singlestore_bq.json', '--project_id=tde-psv-app', 'update', '--transfer_config', '--target_dataset=crashlytics', '--schedule=every 2 hours', 'projects/p/locations/l/transferConfigs/c']
== UTC timestamp ==
  2020-02-24 08:47:23
== Error trace ==
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/bq/bq.py", line 1116, in RunSafely
    return_value = self.RunWithArgs(*args, **kwds)
  File "/path/bq/bq.py", line 4615, in RunWithArgs
    schedule_args=schedule_args)
  File "/path/bq/bigquery_client.py", line 3984, in UpdateTransferConfig
    x__xgafv='2').execute()
  File "/path/bq/bigquery_client.py", line 810, in execute
    BigqueryHttp.RaiseErrorFromHttpError(e)
  File "/path/bq/bigquery_client.py", line 788, in RaiseErrorFromHttpError
    BigqueryClient.RaiseError(content)
  File "/path/bq/bigquery_client.py", line 2385, in RaiseError
    raise BigqueryError.Create(error, result, [])
BigqueryInterfaceError: Error reported by server with missing error fields. Server returned: {u'error': {u'status': u'INVALID_ARGUMENT', u'message': u'Request contains an invalid argument.', u'code': 400}}
========================================

Unexpected exception in update operation: Bigquery service returned an invalid reply in update operation: Error reported by server with missing error fields. Server returned:
{u'error': {u'status': u'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
u'message': u'Request contains an invalid argument.', u'code': 400}}.

Please make sure you are using the latest version of the bq tool and try again. If this problem persists, you may have encountered a bug in the bigquery client. Please file a bug
report in our public issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0
Please include a brief description of the steps that led to this issue, as well as any rows that can be made public from the following information:
```

We might get the impression that this is not possible for this kind of datasets / Firebase projects, but we can't see to find any clean answer on that.

Comment: Can you confirm that you can do the same within BigQuery web UI?

Comment: I've done some tests in the same user scenario, updating Bigquery transfer configuration, and so far your `bq update` command looks good, however I've used Python 3.7.5 instead of Python 2.7.16 and the same `bg` tool version 2.0.53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the data export is only available once per 24 hours. We are looking into changing this behavior. Please stay up to date on the Firebase blog for any announcements.